# Inheriting a method with the same name but different return type

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding

I can see that it doesn't work since I tried it. I just cannot explain why it have to be like that.

```
public int getValue() {
     return 2 * a;
}

public String getValue() {
     return "" + b * super.getValue();
}
```

The second method is from a class which is the child class of the class which implements the first getValue() method.

Why can't the same name be enough for overriding the method? The only argument that could come to my mind is that it would be against the "is a"-relation, because the class of the second method which is extended with A has to have the same abilities as A, and if you override the return type you break that law, right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is to prevent situation like this

```
class Base {
    public int getValue(){
        return 42;
    }
}
class Derived extends Base{
    public String getValue(){
        return "42";
    }
}
```

Now what should be returned here?

```
Base b = new Derived();
int value = b.getValue();
```

Because of `b` being `Base` type reference we should be able to safely assume that result of `getValue` will be `int`, but because of late-binding (dynamic-binding) `getValue` will execute code from `Derived` class so it will return String `"42"` not `int` which would cause problems.

---

Only situation when changing return type of overridden method is safe is when new return type extends/implements old return type:

```
public Fruit getValue(){
    ....    
}
```

can be overridden with something like

```
public Banana getValue(){
    ....    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because in Java a method signature comprises it's name and parameter types. You cannot have two methods with the same signature.

Read [this Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.htmlhttp://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) on defining methods.

As to why; what happens when I, for example, do:

```
final Object object = getValue();
```